# How to calculate 2 sigma circular approximation for GNSS positional accuracy?

Tags: gps, accuracy, accuracy-assessment

I'm using `gpsd` application and I get the positional accuracy related data, i.e.,
`semi-major axis accuracy semi-minor axis accuracy and semi-major axis orientation` of the error ellipse. These values are in `1 sigma`

I have to get `2 sigma` data for `circular estimation` using these values.

I went through these links:
[Link1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_error_probable)
[Link2](https://www.xyht.com/surveying/part-1-foundations-for-computing-error-ellipses/)
[Link3](https://www.xyht.com/surveying/error-ellipses/)
[Link4](https://gssc.esa.int/navipedia//index.php/Accuracy)

I could not really figure out a way to calculate the `2 sigma` circular estimation. Please suggest a method to get this. Please suggest more material to read about this.